Angular error: "This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found"
after opening the project the error appeared at the app.modules.ts
I also review the post resolve from stack but it is not work.
This pic is the error of mine:

Also pics of the dependencies:


Let me know if you have a solution. Thanks
I just created an angular project by command of:
ng new my-test-app --no-strict --standalone false  --routing false

@Shadab please share the version of typescript plugin you are using, try updating or downgrading it

@NarenMurali  Dear Naren, thanks for response, the pics I just updated is showing the dependencie. it is 5.4.2

In tsconfig.json, I changed the value of "importHelpers" from true to false. It will get rid of the error without needing to change the value of "moduleResolution" to "Node".

After search a lot, I found a solution which works in my case;
step 1) inside the project root (in my case that package was exist but I did it again)

npm install tslib --save

step 2) Inside the tsconfig.json file just replace the "bundler" as a value of the "moduleResolution" key to "Node", and save the file.
I hope it works for you too.
